# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dumps' (Checked for files)

Tags: json, python-2.7, import, attributeerror

I am trying to configure an account with a JSON file, but it is giving an AttributeError. I have checked the location of the JSON it is importing. I have been fiddling with this for a few days now and I cannot seem to find the source of this issue. The `__init__.py file` in JSON has a dumps function defined in it. I am new to python, so I would like to apologize in advance if there is a mistake to this that I overlooked or if there is a formatting issue. Thank you.

Input:

```
import sys
import json
import time
import Adafruit_GPIO.SPI as SPI
import Adafruit_MAX31855.MAX31855 as MAX31855

__Author__ = 'Zach'

CLK = 11
DO = 25

sensor1 = MAX31855.MAX31855(CLK, 13, DO)
sensor2 = MAX31855.MAX31855(CLK, 29, DO)
sensor3 = MAX31855.MAX31855(CLK, 05, DO)
sensor4 = MAX31855.MAX31855(CLK, 06, DO)
sensor5 = MAX31855.MAX31855(CLK, 20, DO)
sensor6 = MAX31855.MAX31855(CLK, 21, DO)
sensor7 = MAX31855.MAX31855(CLK, 12, DO)
sensor8 = MAX31855.MAX31855(CLK, 16, DO)

try:
    config_data = open('/home/pi/TempMonitor/picloud_config.json').read()
    config = json.loads(config_data)
except:
    print 'Failed to load config data from picloud_config.json.  Exiting.'
    raise

host = config['aggregate_host']
room = config['room']
location = config['location']
api_key = config['api_key']
app_key = config['app_key']
dc = config['dc']

options = {
    'api_key': api_key,
    'app_key': app_key
}

tags = [
    'dc:' + dc,
    'room:' + room,
    'location:' + location
]

from datadog import initialize
from datadog import api
initialize(**options)

print('Press Ctrl-C to quit.')

print json
temp1 = float(sensor1.readTempC())
print('T1: {0:0.3F}*C'.format(temp1))
api.Metric.send(metric='sls.p7.temperature1', points=temp1, host=host, tags=tags)
temp2 = float(sensor2.readTempC())
print('T2: {0:0.3F}*C'.format(temp2))
api.Metric.send(metric='sls.p7.temperature2', points=temp2, host=host, tags=tags)
temp3 = float(sensor3.readTempC())
print('T3: {0:0.3F}*C'.format(temp3))
api.Metric.send(metric='sls.p7.temperature3', points=temp3, host=host, tags=tags)
temp4 = float(sensor4.readTempC())
print('T4: {0:0.3F}*C'.format(temp4))
api.Metric.send(metric='sls.p7.temperature4', points=temp4, host=host, tags=tags)
temp5 = float(sensor5.readTempC())
print('T5: {0:0.3F}*C'.format(temp5))
api.Metric.send(metric='sls.p7.temperature5', points=temp5, host=host, tags=tags)
temp6 = float(sensor6.readTempC())
print('T6: {0:0.3F}*C'.format(temp6))
api.Metric.send(metric='sls.p7.temperature6', points=temp6, host=host, tags=tags)
temp7 = float(sensor7.readTempC())
print('T7: {0:0.3F}*C'.format(temp7))
api.Metric.send(metric='sls.p7.temperature7', points=temp7, host=host, tags=tags)
temp8 = float(sensor8.readTempC())
print('T8: {0:0.3F}*C'.format(temp8))
api.Metric.send(metric='sls.p7.temperature8', points=temp8, host=host, tags=tags)
```

Output:

```
<module 'json' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py'>
T1: NAN*C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "gather_temps.py", line 56, in <module>
    api.Metric.send(metric='sls.p7.temperature1', points=temp1, host=host, tags=tags)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/datadog/api/metrics.py", line 120, in send
    return super(Metric, cls).send(attach_host_name=True, **metrics_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/datadog/api/resources.py", line 68, in send
    attach_host_name=attach_host_name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/datadog/api/api_client.py", line 112, in submit
    body = json.dumps(body)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'dumps'
```

Comment: I wrote it as __init__.py, I don't know why it was changed.     It got changed in this too, but there are underscores in the init file

Comment: The usual explanation for problems like this is that you have a file named json.py somewhere, that is being found before the real json module.  Use ``import json; print json.__file__`` to see where it is.

Comment: @jasonharper Thanks for checking my question. I did check it and it got gave me back an answer saying that it was finding the correct file with the defined dumps function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was that the Datadog directory had a few files that were going to the wrong folders. After some uninstalling and reinstalling of directories. I got it to work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

One thing I notice is that your output is saying that temp1 is `NAN`, which means Not a Number.  Something is going wrong with your `temp1 = float(sensor1.readTempC())` I think.  Fixing this might inadvertently fix your JSON error too, since it's possible (likely) that `api.Metric.send` assumes that the inputs are proper (and not `NAN`).

Comment: The NAN is just the readout from my temperature sensor. I plugged it in and ran it first, but it was having the same issue. If I connect the thermocouple it gives me a number, but without the thermocouple it is just a NAN.